# django user creation using UserCreationForm issue

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

As per youtube tutorial the user is created with exactly same method but mine doesn't work. Why?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import CreateUserForm

def registerView(request):
    form=CreateUserForm()

    if request.method=="POST":
        form=CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,'Account was successfully created for '+ user)
            return redirect('login')

    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,"accounts/register.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']
```

Why is a user not created?

Comment: Can you provide stack trace of error ?

Comment: can you explain the exact issue? which views are rendered?